# Testing for sameness

Tags: c++11, boost, tdd

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testing_sameness) {
    Dependency dep;
    T foo(dep);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(dep, foo.dep());
}
```

In a test like this, how to write the last line in order to test that the `dep()` method really returns the same object as injected over the constructor?

The underlying class should not implement additional methods like overloading the `==` operator.

Ideally, I would like to simply compare the addresses of both objects. The method is declared as:

```
Dependency dep() : const;
```

Writing this test is more for educational purposes, I wouldn't test getters like that in practice.

Comment: If there's no `operator==`, then what exactly does  "the same" mean? Under what circumstances would you consider two distinct instances of class `Dependency` to be "the same"? Define that, and you'll know how to test for this condition.

Comment: The same means "the same memory address". I have already stated that in my question.

Comment: Two distinct instances would never have the same memory address; that's what makes them distinct. Besides, `foo.dep()` is an rvalue - you can't even take its address. But if you could, it would certainly be different from `&dep`. You are passing `Dependency` around by value; it's being copied in the process; all those copies are located at different addresses.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The constructor takes a reference to `Dependency` as a parameter.

Comment: And what does it do with that reference - stores the actual reference, or makes a copy? In any case, `dep()` method returns by value, so a copy is made there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it stores the reference.

Comment: Make `dep()` also return that reference, then you can write `&dep == &(foo.dep())`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I get `error: taking address of temporary`

Comment: Like I said - you would need to make `dep()` return `Dependency&`. As written, it returns a copy, which of course is not "the same" as the original, under your definition of sameness.